# Коридор – это длинные сени (об истории слов)

Tags: лексика

По словам Карамзина,  коридор (в конце XVIII века)  – это длинные сени, слово достаточно новое,  еще требует пояснения. Само же слово «сени» образовалось от  русского "сень" - проход, галерея, навес, кров в XIV – XVI веках. Какое-то время они существовали вместе, но потом «сени» ушли из языка. Почему именно так сложилась история этих двух слов? Можно ли более точно указать временные пределы их существования  и первое употребление  в языке?

Примеры:

«Мне надлежало идти **через длинные сени или коридор,** где в печальном сумраке представились глазам моим распятия и лампады угасающие» [Н. М. Карамзин. Письма русского путешественника (1793)].

«…а падчерицу свою она **вывела в сени** и посадила в чулан под корыто, дабы король не мог ее увидеть [Сказка о Строевой дочери (1794-1795)].

Спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну да, коридор - это длинные сени, если речь идёт о... первом этаже. А хоть бы даже цокольном.

А вот младенчик Тургенев коридором пробирался в сени: «Я находился в таком страхе, в таком ужасе, что ночью решил бежать. Я уже встал, потихоньку оделся и в потёмках пробрался по коридору в сени…»

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Временные рамки трудно обозначить: где есть изба, там и сени будут. А где-то ещё и дома такие уцелели, с сенями, - их по-другому и не назвать.

А этимологически слово   сѣнь восходит к праславянскому языку ([тут](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8) и [тут](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/wordhistory/102/%D0%9E%D0%A1%D0%95%D0%9D%D0%98%D0%A2%D0%AC)). Исконное то есть. И ещё не мёртвое.

> Ф. И. Буслаев в «Исторической грамматике русского языка. Синтаксис»
>   писал: «...Одно и то же слово в различные времена, или по различным
>   наречиям одного и того же языка, имеет различные значения: так слово
>   сѣни в древнерусском имеет значение залы или жилой комнаты вообще
>   (откуда выражение: сенные девушки), а теперь означает, напротив того,
>   такую комнату, в которой не живут, но которая с надворья ведет к жилым
>   покоям...»

Нашла интересное [на форуме](http://forum.lingvo.ru/actualthread.aspx?tid=16522):

> ...Сени, похоже, не всегда были просто холодным пристроем к избе. Вот,
>   например, что находится на *сени* в фольклоре:
>
> Пошол-то Владимир на широкой двор:
>   У Чурила первы сени решетчатые,
>   У Чурила друти сени серебряные,
>   У Чурила третьи сени были на золоти.
>
> Ко полуночи и двор поспел:
>   Три терема златоверховаты,
>   Да трои сени
>   косящетые,
>   Да трои сени решетчатые.
>   Хорошо в теремах изукрашено:
>   На
>   небе солнце — в тереме солнце,
>   На небе месяц — в тереме месяц,
>   На
>   небе звезды — в тереме звезды,
>   На небе заря — в тереме заря
>   И вся
>   красота поднебесная.
>
> В таком контексте явно не просто бытовой чуланчик упоминается, скорее
>   это важный, парадный элемент дома...

У Даля:

Сенница или сень -

[навес у дома на столбах, крытое крыльцо, галерея, балкон...](https://slovari.yandex.ru/~%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8/%D0%A2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C%20%D0%94%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8F/%D0%A1%D0%95%D0%9D%D0%98%D0%A2%D0%AC/) и там же *прихожая*.

Исчезли из языка сени в значении [дом вообще; судебное место; архиерейское подворье; паперть; княжий дворец.](https://slovari.yandex.ru/~%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8/%D0%A2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C%20%D0%94%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8F/%D0%A1%D0%95%D0%9D%D0%98%D0%A2%D0%AC/)

Справка о сенях на сегодняшний день:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот это уже похоже на современный коридор:

> Сени с переходами встарь связывали разные части барских хором и
>   примыкали к терему...

С коридором - проще.

Лев Успенский:

[**КОРИДОР**](http://www.pochemyneinache.com/alfavit/10/str157.html)

> Если перевести буквально, получится "бегалище". Слово это пришло к
>   нам из Франции или Германии, но в его основе лежит латинское
>   "куррэрэ": в Италии оно дало слово "corridore" - длинное узкое
>   помещение, галерея. Вам, вероятно, попадалось в литературе испанское
>   слово "коррида" - "бой быков"? Оно того же корня и, собственно, значит
>   "беготня".

Да, ещё как разговорное фиксируется обзывание [городской прихожей](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%80) коридором, - незачот... (По ссылке - все лексические значения.)

Коридор в русском лет на семьсот моложе сеней, год его рождения зафиксирован:

> Происходит от итал. corridore «бегун», от correre «бежать», далее из
>   лат. currere «бегать, бежать», из  праиндоевр. *kers- «бежать». Русск.
>   коридор — **впервые в 1710 г.**; заимств. через нем. Korridor или
>   франц. corridor.

Comment: Галина, спасибо за ответ. Да, в наших городских квартирах сени категорически отсутствуют, зато есть прихожая, передняя, даже и холл иногда встречается (= просторная передняя в квартире, в доме). Осталось представить, почему сени были "решетчатые",  и еще интересно, в каком произведении в  далеком 1710 году упоминается слово  "коридор".

Comment: Серёжа, спасибо за меня спасание! ))) А сени "на золоти" Вас не взволновали? По "косящетым" я даже вопрос задала; может, если предположить на секундочку, что "паркетные", то мало ли из чего решётка решётчатости? Типо как в Летнем саду? )))  Чтобы какое-нито помещеньице городской квартиры называли передней, не доводилось слышать... А колидора я вряд ли найду... (((

Comment: Фасмер рулит! "Коридо́р впервые в 1710 г.; **см. Смирнов 162**; народн. колидо́р. Через нем. Korridor или франц. corridor «узкая галерея вокруг укрепления» из прованс. соrrеdоr или ит. corridore — от лат. currere «бежать»; см. Преобр. I, 354.

Comment: Шанский просто отсылает к Петру... "коридор Заимств. в Петровскую эпоху из нем. яз., где Korridor «коридор» < «проход» < франц. corridor, через итал. посредство восходящего к лат. currere «бежать, идти». Ср. аллея. Школьный этимологический словарь русского языка. Происхождение слов. — М.: Дрофа Н. М. Шанский, Т. А. Боброва 2004".

Comment: Коридор здания Двенадцати коллегий: http://virtualtrip.museums.spbu.ru/content/spbu_3.html Правда, это уже 1720-е...

Comment: Грамота уверяет, что  ПЕРЕДНЯЯ - это первая при входе в квартиру нежилая комната для снятия верхней одежды, обуви; прихожая. Раздеться в передней. Толпиться в передней. Тесная, маленькая, просторная п.

Comment: Да, в коридоре есть нечто большее, чем просто проходное помещение, нечто сакральное, символическое. Существовала особая коридорная архитектура, например, в конце XIX-начале XX вв.  среди доходных домов.  Также в советское время школы, общежития, гостиницы.

Comment: Что такое передняя, я знаю из литературы. Но видеть не приходилось. А! Нечто похожее было в Риге,  югендстиль, - такой пятачок перед коридором; но там всё - нерусское, даже 4-метровая комната для прислуги... В объявлениях: сдаётся квартира - 2, 5 комнаты. ))) Три отпуска жила в центре, на тогдашней Суворова... http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/1511808-kakoe-stihotvorenie-cvetaevoj-imeetsja-v-vidu-v-gazetnoj-state-sm.html - мой рассказ, в конце.